# set contourf's lowest level to be white in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using contourf from pyplot. Because of my colormap, the background is a light blue colour, but I just want it to be white. Is there a way to set the colour of the lowest level in contourf to be white? I'm looking for something similar to [seaborn's](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html) `shade_lowest=False`.

Comment: look into `clim` option i.e. the corresponding numerical limits for the colour map.

Comment: That looks promising, how do I get the threshold for the last level?

Comment: Does `cmap.set_under(color='w')` where `cmap` is the `Colormap` you are using achieve what you want? This will set out-of-range values to white.

Comment: I got it working by setting the levels manually and using clim.